# Problem with MIME Types when upgrading to Tomcat 9

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, mime-types

I have an old java servlet/jsp web site at hopirockets.com, circa 2000. It has been running on an oldstable debian server with tomcat 7 and java 8. I upgraded the OS to stable (buster) debian this weekend, and tomcat 7 would not run. The upgrade to buster added java 11, so I backed down to the old java 8 using update-alternatives, but the site would still not load. I then installed tomcat9, deployed the site in the new tomcat9, and the site loaded, sort of. The content loads, but the single css file will not load.

The site loads from tomcat9 in chrome but not firefox. The error in firefox is:

```
`The stylesheet http://hopirockets.com/css/hopi.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.`
```

Chrome loads the style sheet, but gives the warning in the console:

```
`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.hopirockets.com/css/hopi.css".`
```

The index.jsp file had this page directive, which when removed, did not change the behavior in chrome or firefox.

```
`<%@page contentType="text/html"%>`
```

The head tag with the link to the css file looks like this:

`<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Hopi Hawks NAR Section 636">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Hopi Hawks, rocketry, rockets, model rockets, NAR 636, NAR Section 636, egg lofting">

    <title>Hopi Hawks NAR 636</title>
    <link href="/css/hopi.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script language="JavaScript" src="javascript/launch_timer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>`

Long ago I moved away from java/servlets/jsp to python and Django for web sites. I hope someone who works with java web sites more than I do can point me in the right direction to fix this issue.

I have googled this issue and there are many many posts about it, but none of them seem to have the magical incantation needed to fix the problem. So, I thought I would post one more time on this topic for my spercific problem.

Thanks!

Mark

PS I made the upgrades to the OS and tomcat/java to keep current with security patches.

Comment: You can install the old tomcat manually.

Comment: tomcat7  is still installed. It just does not want to run. I would rather upgrade to tomcat9 anyway to have the latest security fixes.

Comment: Then you need to provide much more detail about what doesn’t work.  Exceptions? Anything in the logs?

Comment: I am not trying to get tomcat7 to work on debian buster. I am trying to get the hopirockets.com website to work on tomcat9. Specifically, I am trying to figure out why firefox will not load the hopi.css style sheet, and chrome does. Please see the error messages in the original post.